# Rails: Record checking if user is already following another user through controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Is there a quick way of only getting users that have not followed another user yet?

I'm trying to create a little "Suggested users to follow" module and I want to display only users that are nearby and that have not been followed yet.

This is my controller:

```
@user = User.near(current_user.location,50).where.not(id: current_user.id)
```

In my view I can get the list of users that are nearby and do some kind of check like this:

```
- @user.each do |user|
  - if !current_user.following?(user)
    = user.name
    = <follow btn code>
```

But I want it to already be checked through `@user` in the controller. I think this would be cleaner, or if someone has any other suggestions?

Comment: can you tell us how the `following?(user)` method works in the `User` model?

Comment: @Toby1Kenobi used the `acts_as_follower` gem https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to filter using `select` of the `Enumerable` module (already included in `ActiveRecord` collections)

in the controller:

```
@user = User.near(current_user.location,50).where.not(id: current_user.id)
@user = @user.select{ |u| !current_user.following?(u) }
```

but be warned that this will change the type of `@user` from an `ActiveRecord` collection to a simple array.